# Is there a way to trade cities?

Tags: warhammer-total-war

Since The campaign map is RISK like, and there are benefits to holding whole territories, is there any way to trade cities? this is in single player campaign mode. Feel free to answer for MP too.

Comment: I haven't found a way to trade cities. But if you are playing the dwarfs, greenskins or empire if you are friendly enough a group of the same faction. You can ask them too join you, giving you all their cities and armies.

Comment: The option Lyrion's talking about is called Confederation and is available with factions of the same type as you (e.g. Empire provinces if you're playing as Empire). For other factions you have a Subjugate option to make them your vassal (iirc it's not available for all factions, no chance to subjugate the Norsca tribes, but for the Empire it's available for Bretonnia, Dwarfs, other human provinces and maybe Undead, for Greenskins you can subjugate the Savage Orcs tribes and Confederate the regular Greenskins ones).

Comment: @Autar Vampire lords can only subjugate, no confederations.

Comment: @Lyrion OK, makes sense since anyway there are only 3 Vampire factions and two of them are at war at the beginning of the campaign.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there is no way to trade cities. I think in the Warhammer lore, no faction will trade their cities with another faction, even with confederations.

But, when you keep all cities of a region and you get the benefits, if a faction that's your vassal has a city on a region and you have the other city on the same region, you can gain the decree's benefits, but you will eventually confederate with that faction. There are huge benefits in having that city beyond just getting some money from your vassal and having the decree.